# Cart value resets on browser refresh

Tags: reactjs

In ECommerce React project, I've created cart when clicked, changes to 'In Cart' and is then disabled which shows the product is in cart and can't be clicked back, but, when browser is refreshed Cart value resets back.

Following is the code reference

Product.js

```
export default class Product extends Component {
    render() {
        const {id, title, img, price, inCart} = this.props.product;
        const dataValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart'))

        return (
            <ProductWrapper className="col-9 mx-auto col-sm-6 col-lg-3 my-3 " >
                <div className="card" >
                    <ProductConsumer>
                        {(value) => (
          <div  className="img-container p-3" >

         <img style={imageSize}  src={img} alt="product" 
         className="card-img-top center img-fluid img-responsive"/>


        <button className="cart-btn" disabled={inCart?true:false}
        onClick={() => {value.addToCart(id)}}> 
        {console.log('DATA VALUE', dataValue)}
        { inCart ? (
            <p className="text-capitalize mb-0" disabled>
            {" "}
            In Cart</p>
        ) : (
            <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"/>
        )}
          </button>
        </div>)}
       </ProductConsumer> 
       </div> 
    </ProductWrapper>   
         );
    }

}
```

ProductList.js (Mapping list of products)

```
export default class ProductList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <ProductConsumer>
                 {value => {

             return value.products.map((product, key) => {
             return  <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                                      });
                                }}
                            </ProductConsumer>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route render={({location}) => (
                  <Switch location={location}>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ProductList}/>
                  </Switch>
        )} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've tried with localStorage but no effect. What can be done to make the cart value store in localStorage, so that when refreshed 'In Cart' remains. Any appropriate solution?

Following is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/tdgwm

Comment: "I've tried with localStorage but no effect." In the code shown here, there is only code for getting data from localStorage, nothing for storing the data in localStorage. Please show the code that stores the data.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Please see the code at sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/tdgwm

Answer (score 0):

```
<button
   className="cart-btn"
              disabled={inCart ? true : false}


              onClick={() => {
                value.addToCart(id);
                localStorage.setItem("added", "In Cart");
                console.log(localStorage.getItem("added"));
              }}
            >
              {localStorage === null ? (
                <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart" />
              ) : (
                <p className="text-capitalize mb-0" disabled>
                  {" "}
                  {localStorage.getItem("added")}
                </p>
              )}


            </button>
```

I took a quick look at this. The above code will get the localStorage item set and render the in cart value. However, I will leave it to you to apply it to the individual product and update the conditionality for the icon/in cart piece. I'll be on for a little bit longer if you have any questions. But basically you need to see if localstorage is set prior to rendering.

Comment: On refresh the cart is not disabled although the product is already in cart

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't check the local storage inCart value in the Product.js

I have added another condition like below and check it within `inCart` in the conditions

```
...
...
const localInCart = dataValue 
  && dataValue.find(i => i.id === id) 
  && dataValue.find(i => i.id === id).inCart;
...
...
...
(inCart || localInCart) ? ...)
```

you can see the result on codesandbox; https://codesandbox.io/s/mobile-store-ufxgp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark